# Encoding content to UTF-8 insite a url that turns to a file :\

Tags: php, utf-8, calendar, icalendar

i'm using this code to get one of my calendars from icloud. It's a url that turns into a file for download (should be *.ics but i can leave without it) . the problem is that the file is ANSI. i want it to be downloaded as UTF-8.

```
<?php
$file = "http://p04-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/subscribe/1/xxxzzzccc".$_GET['file']."";
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
@readfile($file);
?>
```

Thanks

EDIT:

so, i tried a different road :

```
<?php
$url = 'http://p04-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/subscribe/1/xxxzzzccc';
$img = 'z.ics';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
$utfconvert = file_get_contents("z.ics");
$saveit = fopen("zz.ics","w");
fwrite($saveit,utf8_encode($utfconvert));
fclose($saveit);
?>
```

but the new file is saved without bom and google calendar STILL doesn't show the right characters. I've spend 3 hours on this and counting.

Comment: Why do you want to change the encoding from the remote site?

Comment: The url is on a remote site but the php is on my server. The encoding change is because i'm using hebrew that looks like @%$&^@ if it's not in UTF-8. When i import the link to my php to google calendar UTF-8 is the only way to go.

Comment: The file is ANSI and you want to convert it to UTF-8? utf8_encode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Comment: I tired that and it didn't worked. First i thought it was something with my code but then i saw this "Please note that utf8_encode only converts a string encoded in ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the iCal output is actually UTF-8 encoded by the server when you output it. You then may want to add additional headers:

```
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the calendar data itself is utf8 encoded? Can you post up what the code that is being output looks like?

Comment: It worked! The original code had {} missing. Thanks for the help

Comment: missed{}  where ?, can u post the line added with this